# Trigger sometimes does not work, I do not understand why

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I need your help.

I have an active google form where customers register.
When I submit the form I have 3 activators that run me scripts, especially they convert the ITALIAN date format (dd-mm-yyyy) to USA (yyyy-mm-dd).

**Start of action: Upon submitting the form**

The problem I find is this.
These scripts do not always work even if from the control panel I find that it has been executed correctly without reporting errors.

*A code example:*

```
function respondToFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];


  // Format column I
  var column1 = sheet.getRange("F:F");
  var column2 = sheet.getRange("J:J");
  var column3 = sheet.getRange("K:K");
  var column4 = sheet.getRange("A:A");


  // Set new date format on column I
  column1.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');
  column2.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');
  column3.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');
  column4.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');

};
```

**When the problem occurs, all 3 triggers fail.**
The non-functioning occurs 20/30% of the time and this discontinuous "error" does not make me understand what the problem is.

Do you have any suggestions for me?
Thank you so much for your invaluable help.
Mauro

Comment: You should not use those kinds of ranges because they tend to return lots of nulls at the end.   Use `getRange(row,col,sheet.getLastRow())` or .filter them

Comment: When the triggers fail - what is the error message you receive?

Comment: @ ziganotschka  The problem is that I don't get any kind of error message. :-(

Comment: @Cooper  Thanks for your invaluable help.
Not being very programming expert could you show me how to replace the row?

Example:
var column1 = sheet.getRange(row,col,sheet.getLastRow("F:F"));

It's right?

Comment: So did you check you execution logs by going from the Script editor UI on View->Executions? If the trigger ran - you will see it in the logs (which you can expand to see error messages or logs that you implemented in your code for troubleshooting - please implement the latter). So did the trigger fire correctly but the script did not do what you expected it to do?

Comment: @ziganotschka 
I went to the Executions and the LOGs.
The script ran successfully. Status Completed.
It tells me: No logs available for this run

It happens that the trigger fires correctly but the script does not perform the operation.

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem when running the function manually? In this case the problem is likely the one outlined by Cooper.

Comment: @ziganotschka In manual execution everything works correctly. :-(

Comment: is the script running in the form or is it running from the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Cooper
The script is running on the form.
From https://script.google.com/home/triggers I have set the function to run when the form is submitted.

Comment: What is you intention? Formatting the row where the new form data has been inserted?

Comment: Is the spreadsheet that you're accessing the one that is linked to the form?

Comment: @ziganotschka
That's right I would like when a new row is inserted it will be formatted with the required date format.

Comment: @Cooper  Yes, it is the one connected to the module

Answer (score 0):

### The problem with your script running on trigger are likely propagation
issues

It takes some time for a new form response to be inserted into the
spreadsheet, so your number formatting functionality might be run
before the new row gets inserted.

One thing you can do is implement some waiting time at the beginning
at the function, e.g. with
[sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).

However, if you bind your script to the destination spreadsheet
instead of the form itself - you will be able to use the [Google
Sheets event
objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_slides_events)
for `Form submit` which include `range`.

Sample usage:

```
function respondToFormSubmit(e) {   
 var row = e.range.getRow();   
 var sheet = e.range.getSheet();  
 sheet.getRange("F" + row).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');  
 sheet.getRange("J" + row).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');  
 sheet.getRange("K" + row).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');  
 sheet.getRange("A" + row).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd'); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much I tried your code but it gives me this error:
Mistake
ReferenceError: "e" not defined.
respondToFormSubmit @ FormatDATE_2021.gs:7

Comment: Because the event object `e` is only available when a form is being submitted. You can not run this function automatically, you need to bind it to an `On Form Submit` trigger and let it fire automatically when a form response is being submitted.

Comment: I try to set it so I see when registering a new customer if everything is ok.
In the meantime, thanks for your precious help

Comment: You also have to put the e parameter in the function declaration of the on submit trigger function

Comment: It would be better just to put your script into the spreadsheet and use the on form submit for the spreadsheet rather than the on submit for the form just to be clear there are two ways that you can use the on submit trigger one is  on the form and one is on the spreadsheet

Comment: @Cooper 
Thanks for your help
Unfortunately, being an inexperienced USER, I can't quite understand your suggestions :-(

If I insert the script in the spreadsheet how can I then say that when the form is sent it must be activated?

Comment: It ness to be the specific destination spreadsheet for the form responses - not any spreadsheet. And you need to set the function on trigger, just like you did when binding it to the form.

Comment: @cooper
As per your advice, I inserted the scripts in the spreadsheet and started the trigger on the spreadsheet.
What should I put on "Select the type of event":
- At the opening
- To the modification (I put this)
- At the exchange
- When submitting the form

Now I see what happens when customers register.
Thanks

Comment: @Cooper Thank you so much for the suggestions, I made the changes you recommended and everything seems ok for now.
I have not changed the SCRIPTS but I have only changed the activation from the spreadsheet. Thanks a lot to everyone for your valuable advice.
Mauro